# How to show $\log x$ and $e^x$ never meet.

Tags: graphing-functions

I want to show $\log x$ and $e^x$ never meet without having any graphing calculator.

Comment: Hint: $e^x>x>\log x.$

Comment: Please explain your mathematics background so that you receive responses that are appropriate to your skill level.  For instance, do you know calculus?  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Consider the power series for $e^x$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
x<1+x< e^x.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now apply his twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you are familiar with calculus, but that would be my approach. I'm also not sure if you're using "log" to mean natural log (that's what I use in my answer) or log base 10. My answer can be adapted to work for log base 10 as well.

First note that $e^1=e$ and $\log(1)=0<e$, so $e^x> \ln(x)$ at $x=1$.

Next, $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Thus $\frac{d}{dx}e^x  >e$ for $x>1$, and $\frac{d}{dx}\log(x) < 1<e$ for $x>1$. So the derivative of $e^x$ is greater than the derivative of $\ln(x)$ for $x>1$. Hence, if $x>1$:
$$e^x =\int_1^xe^t \ dt +e^1>\int_1^x \frac{1}{x} \ dx  = \ln(x).$$

For $x<1$ we have $e^x>0>\ln(x)$.

Comment: I got another approach as e^ x and ln x are inverse of each other so they are symmetric to y = x and for all x》0  f(x)=e^x>x so its image that is ln x will lie below the line hence they will never meet for X greater than zero and for X less than zero there is no confusion